# How do I know which of my laptop GPUs are running games?

Tags: laptop, graphics, nvidia-geforce, intel-graphics

My laptop has 2 GPUs, one of them is the default Intel HD Graphics 3000, and the other the Nvidia Geforce GT 630M. Obviously I want to use the 630M to play my games. How can I assure this is happening? When I go into Start → Run → dxdiag and look at the Display tab, it says that I am using the Intel HD Graphics Family for the display. Does this mean it is being used for games too?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Generally, if your laptop gets hot enough to boil water on, it means your nVidia card is being used.

Answer (score 13):

On the NVidia Control Panel you can choose which graphic card to use, but you can not know which graphic card is running.

If you just want to know which graphic card is running, you can have an icon in the notification area which show the running graphic card.

Here is the explanation to enable it according to [acer website](http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9075/~/determining-which-graphics-card-is-used-with-nvidia-optimus):

> 1 - Click Start and then Control Panel. Select Classic View from the
>   left side of the window.
>
> 2 - Double-click NVIDIA Control Panel.
>
> 3 - Click View and next Display GPU Activity Icon in Notification Area.
>
> 4 - Click the new icon in the notification area. A pop-up will show applications using the   NVIDIA graphics. When the NVIDIA
>   graphics is not used, it will show None.

Comment: I believe this is the answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: In german it is in the menu "Desktop" and then "GPU Aktivitätssymbol im Infobereich anzeigen"

Answer (score 5):

In the Nvidia Control Panel you can specify which GPU to use on a per EXE basis, or which once is on by default. If you are getting poor performance add your game's EXE to the list under `Program Settings` or temporary change the value in `Global Settings`.

[image]

I know for Minecraft I had to add `Java.exe` to my program settings list for it to use the better GPU
while running the game.

Comment: Thanks for the reply buddy, I'll give that a try - do you know if there is anyway to literally just disable the intel one or make sure that the 630m is default for everything?

Comment: Yes, under `Global Settings` select `High performance NVIDIA processor`. Note that you will have a shorter battery life when you are not plugged in and a higher average temperature as programs that don't need the hotter, more power hungry, GPU will still use it anyway. If you are getting bad FPS, then force it to the Nvidia GPU, otherwise just let it autoselect.

Answer (score 2):

Another quick option is to open the windows task manager (ctrl + shift + escape ) and go to the performance tab. There you will find both graphic cards and their usage.

[task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzSxB.png)