# how to check if nvidia or intel graphics is being used

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I have a laptop with nvidia graphic. How can I find if the program is running with nvidia graphics card or with the intel graphics.I searched for this query but could not find the suitable answer?

Comment: In order to get a usable answer, you need to add some details to this question. Start with answering the following; What make & model of laptop is it? What OS are you using? If your laptop has Nvidia graphics, what makes you think its using Intel graphics?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I know which of my laptop GPUs are running games?](http://superuser.com/questions/576560/how-do-i-know-which-of-my-laptop-gpus-are-running-games)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68028/how-do-i-check-if-ubuntu-is-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to look it up is to use System Info.

Start > Run (or Win+R) > MSINFO32

[image: MSIFNO32]

Under Components, look for Display click it, and it will give you info about what windows is using.

[image]

Comment: This doesnt work because it shows both the GPUs one after the other if you have nvidia optimus. This is proper official solution http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/185036

Comment: determine if the nvidia card is being switched to during high load: [**Optimus State Viewer**](http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/26992-optimus-test-tools-finally-in-users-hands/)

Comment: Downvote. The answerer should make clear that this is only an answer for those who work with just one graphics card. If you had two as a dual setup as it is asked for here, this would list two graphics cards. And you would have no clue what is at work. If the answerer made clearer that this is just a nice first step to find out which graphics cards are on your computer at all, I would rethink the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking and asking if dedicated vs integrated being used correct? If so, try looking within your default devices and seeing which appears to be running. Also, try placing under stress (eg: benchmarking program) and seeing how well it runs. If it runs very well; how well you would expect a nvidia graphics card to work, then you are fine. If not it COULD be nvidia being used but a bottleneck. More info needed for diagnosis

Comment: How do "look within your defaut devices"?

Comment: In the device manager, I only see the two graphics cards listet, at work, and ready. Since you do not make clear how to check the devices, I dare to downvote this, and I only do not do so since you throw in the needed keywords to search further on this, namely "dedicated" (NVIDIA) and "integrated" (Intel).