# Very poor connectivity and poor performance on high end specs

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, performance

I recently got a new laptop which has very good specs, it's basically a direct upgrade from my previous laptop - a GTX860M, quad core i7 2.5GHz and 16 GB ram. My old laptop ran Minecraft at 60+ FPS but right now I'm barely running 20 FPS. I've connected my charger and set it at high energy usage. Yet no luck.

Secondly, my internet connection is very poor. My previous laptop got 5 bars of connectivity, but this one mostly 1 bar and sometimes 3 bars, leading me to 3 mbps, while I should get 20-25. My laptop model is a Lenovo 50-70,any help appreciated a lot!

Comment: I would look into what start up programs are running in thew background and stop the ones you don't need. Also you could open your task manager and resource monitor and see what is taking up your CPU and Ram. With those specs you should have no problem on a game like Minecraft. As far as internet connection how far ar you from your AP/wireless router?

Comment: Most new laptops use dual graphic cards, an integrated intel one for basic stuff and - in your case - the GTX for heavier loads. Have you checked if the GTX is actually used by minecraft? Sometimes they have trouble switching correctly.

Comment: It's a brand new laptop, there is absolutely nothing weird or useless running in the background. There's nothing hogging resources. As for connections, not that far away at all. As I said,my previous laptop was easily able to get 3-5 bars on average so this one shouldn't have issues with it either. Rightnow, sitting very close to the router gives me two bars, so I think something is off. Especially because there's a Wi-Fi a few houses down the road which show 5 bars. In response to gartenzaun, how do I check this?

Comment: You should have a program called "Nvidia control panel", open that and go to "manage 3D settings" There you can either set the global settings to always use the nvidia card or add certain programs to be used with the nvidia card. I also found this http://superuser.com/questions/576560/how-do-i-know-which-of-my-laptop-gpus-are-running-games and someone stated they had to add java.exe to the program list in order to play minecraft on high settings. maybe that helps.