# How do I know which of my laptop GPUs are running the games?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, intel-graphics, amd-graphics-card

My laptop has 2 GPUs, one of them is the default Intel HD Graphics 3000, and the other the AMD R7 m445. Obviously I want to use the R7 to play my games. How can I assure this is happening? When I go into Start → Run → dxdiag and look at the Display tab, it says that I am using the Intel HD Graphics Family for the display. Does this mean it is being used for games too? and I am also not getting good FPS even in low settings:

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/576560/how-do-i-know-which-of-my-laptop-gpus-are-running-games?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know which of my laptop GPUs are running games?](https://superuser.com/questions/576560/how-do-i-know-which-of-my-laptop-gpus-are-running-games)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open in start `Power Options`
2. Select **High Performance**
   And then by default you will use the better one.


   #### Otherwise:


   Install AMD controller and setup it in there.
   Or setup it in Intel HD controller.